# Capy-template build errors

Tags: zig

I installed the capy-template with git on ubuntu. I'm getting zillions of windows errors. I'm totally new to zig and I have no clue as to why I'm getting windows errors.

### zig build followed by it's dump of errors.

```bash
$ zig build

zig build-exe okp Debug native: error: the following command failed with 520 compilation errors:
/usr/local/zig/zig build-exe /home/nil/zig/capy/okp/src/main.zig -lgtk+-3.0 -lc --cache-dir /home/nil/zig/capy/okp/zig-cache --global-cache-dir /home/nil/.cache/zig --name okp --mod capy:zigimg,zigwin32:/home/nil/zig/capy/okp/.zigmod/deps/git/github.com/capy-ui/capy/src/main.zig --mod zigimg::/home/nil/zig/capy/okp/.zigmod/deps/git/github.com/capy-ui/capy/vendor/zigimg/zigimg.zig --mod zigwin32::/home/nil/zig/capy/okp/.zigmod/deps/git/github.com/capy-ui/capy/vendor/zigwin32/win32.zig --deps zigwin32,capy --subsystem native --listen=- 
Build Summary: 0/3 steps succeeded; 1 failed (disable with --summary none)
run transitive failure
+- run okp transitive failure
   +- zig build-exe okp Debug native 520 errors
.zigmod/deps/git/github.com/capy-ui/capy/vendor/zigwin32/win32/zig.zig:142:32: error: invalid builtin function: '@intToPtr'
.zigmod/deps/git/github.com/capy-ui/capy/vendor/zigwin32/win32/zig.zig:161:63: error: invalid builtin function: '@ptrToInt'
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a very recent change in compiler. running `zig fmt .zigmod/deps/git/github.com/capy-ui/capy` should fix it.